# Conditional formatting to highlight values that are not in valid date format

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a date column. A contributor to this spreadsheet keeps entering dates in invalid format. I would like to conditionally format the cells in this column to have a red background if the text cannot be interpreted to be a valid date.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this by using a custom formula in the conditional formatting. Assuming that you are conditional formatting the cells A1:A, enter this conditional formula:

```
=NOT(ISDATE(A1))
```